# Installing php5-fpm with php version 5.4.x

Tags: 14.04, php, php-fpm

I'm installing a LEMP stack for the first time, and although I've got everything set up right now, I was hoping to install PHP 5.4.x to work with my Magento installation. Installing `php5-fpm` automatically comes bundled with 5.5.9. Is there a way to install PHP 5.4.x separately and still utilize FPM?

I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04

EDIT:

I ended up installing `phpbrew` and installing PHP 5.4.31. However I don't know how to configure FPM. I would love it if someone could point me to an old distribution of `php-fpm` bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable remi-php54 from `repository` on folder `/etc/apt/sources.list`: 
[image]

And you can install `php5-fpm` with `apt-get install`